# Simple LDAP based centralized web authentication store

Tags: authentication, web-applications, ldap

Internal to our work group we have a number of services running on our web server including build service, wiki, bug tracker, and some homegrown apps. Currently these all require seperate logins for each service.

The main choice i see to centralize user creation between all these services is LDAP, however i am not interested in doing the full enterprise system, attaching logins and shared directories etc all I want is a way of centralizing users in web services.

From playing with openLDAP this seems complete overkill and is a pain to set up. Is there a simpler method, perhaps speaking LDAP protocol or some other way of centralizing authentication without having to hack up custom external authentication scripts for my services?

Comment: Can you tell us what the problems are with OpenLDAP? Then people might be able to address your issues.

Comment: My question is not so much about a problem with OpenLDAP, it's being difficult but i'm sure i could manage. It is more is there a simpler alternative i am missing. The documentation for LDAP in general is very focused around providing active directory like services and controlling enterprise resource management etc. Given that I don't need this functionality is there an easier way?

Comment: LDAP does not provide "active directory like services". Active Directory provides services that are similar to, but incomplete, from an LDAP perspective. The basic protocol and directory information model of LDAP has no mention of enterprise resource management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A centralized authentication store accessed via LDAP is exactly the solution for which you seek. LDAP is

- a small protocol from a wire perspective
- most available LDAP servers are extremely fast
- the protocol and implemented servers are simple
- easy to understand
- easy to administrate
- easily securable

Add replication for redundancy and increased aggregate throughput and it is hard to imagine a better solution.

Comment: Guess i'll continue down this route then, thanks.